# Массив не инициализируется в сервисе Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2, typescript, angular4

Доброе время уток,кря-кря. Пытаюсь сделать систему меток на Ангуляре, но вот не задача есть компонент :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.labels = this.labelservice.labels;
}
addLabel() {
    const label = new Label((this.NameLabel));
    this.labelservice.addLabel(label);
    this.NameLabel = '';
}
```

В нём инициализируется добавление элемента в массив класса метки, есть сервис:

export class LabelService {

```
constructor() {}

labels:Label[] = [];

addLabel( label:Label) {
    this.labels.push(label);
}
deleteLabel(name:string){
    console.log(this.labels);
    for(let i:number = 0; i<this.labels.length;i++){
        if(name = this.labels[i].name){
            this.labels.slice(i,i+1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Который добавляет и удаляет данные с массива, но вот не задача, при попытке удаление с компонента, который является частью массива, т.е. сама метка:

```
 onAction() {
     this.labelService.deleteLabel(this.label.name);
}
```

Я не могу найти элемент, ибо сам массив в сервисе пуст.

Так вот как мне решить эту проблему и почему собственно :

```
this.labels.push(label);
```

добавляет элемент не в массив сервиса, а добавляет его в массив компонента.
всем спасибо за внимание

Comment: массив сервиса и массив компонента в твоем случае это одно и то же. По приведенному куску коду нельзя сказать в чем конкретно ошибка

Comment: двойное (хотя бы) равно в иф не помешало бы. Нужно больше кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно, решил вопрос по другому- воспользовался EventEmitter:
[https://metanit.com/вweb/angular2/2.10.php](https://metanit.com/%D0%B2web/angular2/2.10.php) - подробно прочитать.
 исправил  в

```
deleteLabel(name:string){
    for(let i:number = 0; i<=this.labels.length;i++){
        if(name == this.labels[i].name){
           this.labels.splice(i,i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

slice на splice может кто-то тоже не заметил буковку,  и в родительском элементе повесил слушатель :

```
  <app-label *ngFor="let label of labels" [label]="label" (deleteName)="deleteLabel($event)"></app-label>
```

а в дочернем  добавил в компонент:

```
 @Output() deleteName: EventEmitter<string>;
onAction() {
    console.log(this.label);
     this.deleteName.emit(this.label.name);
}
```

а в темплейте :

```
   <h4  (click)="onAction()">{{label.name}}</h4>
```

Спасибо за внимание